# How to check current loop state in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, loops

I'm using `Bootstrap` carousel with `Rails`, here is how it looks like:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

    <% @post.gallery_images.each do |i| %>
    <div class="item">
       <%= image_tag i.image.url, class: 'img-responsive' %>
    </div>
    <% end %>

</div>
```

but for the `item` div I need to set a class `active` for the carousel to be able to start and then select which image is the one to be shown. I believe I need JS for this to be accomplished, the end result should look somewhat like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

    <% @post.gallery_images.each do |i| %>
    <div class="item active">
       <%= image_tag i.image.url, class: 'img-responsive' %>
    </div>
    <% end %>

</div>
```

How can I make the `active` class update dynamically in cooperation with the `Rails` loop?

Comment: on what condition you need to add `active` class?

Comment: You can't change the active element using Ruby, you would have to do that in JavaScript. From Ruby you can only set the *initial* active element. Which would you like it to be? The first one? All of them? (your last code snippet does this latter thing, sets all of them to `active` to begin with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Amadan implies, you will have to change the active item through DOM manipulation (ie JavaScript). If you want the first item to be the initial active one:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <% @post.gallery_images.each.with_index do |img, index| %>
    <% if index == 0 %>
    <div class="item active">
    <% else %>
    <div class="item">
    <% end %>
       <%= image_tag img.image.url, class: 'img-responsive' %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

There are, of course, more elegant solutions than this. But this is just go give you some quick help.

Answer (score 0):

Although Rails will seem like the popular option, you can easily do this with JavaScript.

Add the following code (either line) to the bottom on your template.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* add 'active' class to the first item */
$('.carousel-inner .item').first().addClass('active');

/* add 'active' class to the last item */
$('.carousel-inner .item').last().addClass('active');
</script>
```